# azure mobile services entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to create an azure mobile services .net back end

i download the source sample from azure web site and try to run it on my computer everything works.
when i publish to azure then entity framework is having problem to connect to azure sql. ( I'm using a new database in an existing server)

the error is permission issue.

Somehow in azure the entity framework is trying to log in with a user YAtdHDYMBgLogin that doesn't exists in my database.

I guess the issue is the new connection string azure mobile services is assign to my code.

Is there anyway to change the user who connect to the db. I can remove the MS_TableConnectionString and put it hard coded on the web.config in release mode but i want to know if there is a way to workaround this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Add a new "ConnectionString" element to the `appSettings` element in your web.config:

`<add key="ConnectionString" value="<your connection string"/>`

2. Pass this to your db context:

`public MyContext() : base(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]) { }`

3. You can override this in the "app settings" section in the Configure tab in the Azure management portal. Just create a new "ConnectionString" variable and give it the value you want.

When you run your app locally, it will use the value in web.config. When you run it on the instance, it will use the value you configured in the portal.